# What is the compiled generation of the aidl file in Aosp and where is it stored

Tags: android, build, android-source, aidl

After building AOSP project,I can't find compile generation of aidl file.For example, I can't find IAccountManager.java corresponding to IAccountManager.aidl（/AOSP/frameworks/base/core/java/android/accounts/IAccountManager.aidl）
Is its compiled generation a java file, and where should it be stored

Answer (score 1):

[image]Yes, there should be some middle gen java files and generally stored in (take your file as example):out/soong/.intermediates/frameworks/base/framework/android_common/gen/aidl/frameworks/base/core/java/android/accounts/IAccountManager.java

Comment: I build aosp successfully， but there is no "gen" directory under the "android_common" directory. Is there a problem with .mk file or .bp file?what should i do

Comment: Assuming that the path of the aidl file has been determined. Is the path you mentioned fixed oryou just give me an example？

Comment: I did AOSP building moment ago, and I searched the out files, the result is exactly what I posted. @bay0max

Comment: @bay0max You can just search you out dir for "IAccountManager.java" using "find -name 'IAccountManager.java' " command to find out where exactly your aosp project aidl gen dir is.

Comment: I have tried but still got nothing